# How to report both selection and outcome equation of selection models with stargazer in r?

Tags: r, stargazer

I have calculated a tobit type 2 model with the selection()-function of the sampleSelection package in R.

I now want to create a regression table with stargazer that officially supports the  sampleSelection package and its 'selection' objects.

```
stargazer(tobit, tobit_2, type = "html", out = "tobit2.html", model.names = TRUE,
      star.char = c("+", "*", "**", "***"), star.cutoffs = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0.001),
      report = 'vc*p', notes = "+ p<0.1; * p<0.05; ** p<0.01; *** p<0.001",
      notes.append = F, selection.equation = TRUE)
```

According to the official documentation it is, however, only possible to report either the selection or the outcome equation. I obviously want to report both next to each other.

> **selection.equation**
>   a logical value that indicates whether the selection equation (when argument is
>   set to TRUE) or the outcome equation (default) will be reported for heckit and
>   selection models from the package sampleSelection

Has anyone encoutered that issue before and has a solution how to report both conveniently in one table?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a (rather dirty) solution which may though still help others:

I set selection.equation to TRUE, duplicate the selection-object and switch reference indices for the selection and outcome equation in the duplicated object. Calling stargazer now on both models gives a table with the selection and the outcome equation (although stargazer still thinks it returned both times the selection equation)

```
# tobit_2 is a selection-object returned from the selection() function
# from the sampleSelection package
tobit_2O <- tobit_2
tobit_2O$param$index$betaO <- tobit_2$param$index$betaS
tobit_2O$param$index$betaS <- tobit_2$param$index$betaO

stargazer(tobit_2, tobit_2O, selection.equation = TRUE,          
column.labels = c("<em>selection</em>", "<em>outcome</em>"))
```